# Why is this not synthesizable? (does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge))

Tags: events, process, vhdl, clock, synthesis

I'm a software engineer (JAVA/C++) and not an electrical engineer so you can imagine that VHDL is thoroughly confusing to me because I have little idea what the synthesizer is trying to do behind the scenes. And it's telling me it can't synthesize what I believe to be a very simple architecture. (in fact it's doing it for several entities I have so I suspect I am misunderstanding some fundamental concept and repeating the architectural mistake in multiple places.)

Why does this not synthesize...
(ERROR - controller.vhd(63): statement is not synthesizable since it does not
hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition. VHDL-1242
Done: error code 2)

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY controller IS
    PORT (
        ack: out STD_LOGIC := '0';
        data_request: in STD_LOGIC
    );
END controller;

ARCHITECTURE logic OF controller IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS (data_request)
    BEGIN
        if (rising_edge(data_request)) then
            -- other logic will be added here
            ack <= '1';
        elsif (falling_edge(data_request)) then
            -- other logic will be added here too
            ack<='0';
        end if;
    END PROCESS;
END logic;
```

(Yes, I am fully aware that the "logic" of the process could be replaced by
ack <= data_request; but my vhdl source is actually much more complex than this
but I have distilled it down to the simplest subset that throws the error. please, don't suggest replacing the process with a different structure/concurrent statement.)

Basically, when the data_request line transitions to high the ack output should be driven high; on the falling edge it should be changed to driven low. (and In each case I want a whole bunch of other stuff to change as well, hence I need the process instead of a concurrent statement, the ack change it just to signal a top-level entity that a request has been completed.)

What is "not holding its value"? What "clock" is it talking about when it says "NOT(clock-edge)"?

I would love an explanation of how to fix this (without changing the structure) and an explanation of what I trying to ask the synthesizer to do and why the synthesizer can't accomplish the goal.

Comment: I may have figured out some reason why... After reading I think the X output in "X <= Y" assignment in sensitivity processes are implement by the synthesizer with a flip-flop attached to the sensitivity event as a clock and I am trying to drive the flip-flop with two different clock sources which flip-flops don't support. Is this correct? How then do you alter an output like ack two different ways according to two different events?

Comment: Your synthesis tool will have HDL guidelines for sequential logic showing the acceptable forms derived from IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn). The issue here is your trying to use both edges of data_request as a dual data rate clock, while DDR is if supported, only available for iO cells and requires special invocation (and uses two flip flops). Generally only one clock edge per process may be supported. Think hardware description language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your signal `ack` is set on rising edge and falling edge only. The synthesis will try to make your component working in the real world, with physics constraints. In other word you must manage the case there is no events.
In your case you just have to add a `else` statement in your `if`, like the following way :

```
architecture logic of controller is

signal ack_s : std_logic := '0';

begin
    process(data_request)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(data_request)) then
            -- other logic will be added here
            ack_s <= '1';
        elsif (falling_edge(data_request)) then
            -- other logic will be added here too
            ack_s <= '0';
        else then
            ack_s <= ack_s;
        end if;
    end process;

    ack <= ack_s;    -- You map the output on the internal signal

end architecture logic;
```

This way your signal is always mapped to a value. If you try to draw the schematics you will get the point. Also you must use a `signal` because you can't to the `ack <= ack;` when `ack` is an output.
As a tip I recommend you to always have an `else` statement every time you do a `if` block because on a circuit in the real world you always need a default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

VHDL is just a programming language, and a lot of structures are actually possible. However, you want to program VHDL for a device (FPGA?). That means you have to program it according to specific rules.

To be able to detect an edge, you have to observe a value at two moments in time: a before and an after. Thus you have to introduce the concept of time in your code. "signal x was '0' at t-1 and is '1' at t."

The concept of time as in clock time is not known in most programmable devices. You as a programmer have to introduce it. In most digital circuits you would use an oscillator with a certain frequency for this, mostly dubbed 'clock'.

Digital logic has an other issues, and that is latency. Electricity does not travel with infinite speed through the logic. Thus you have to take latencies through different traveling paths into account. This makes it very difficult to design asynchronous logic. Alternatively you would store values in memory elements at specific places to fix the timing issue, called synchronous logic. These elements are usually registers.

Why I explain this, is to motivate the reason to introduce a clock into your design for you specific requirements. You need to remember the previous state of `data_request` in order to observe a change.

```
    signal data_request_old : std_logic;
begin
    data_request_old <= data_request when rising_edge(clk);
    if data_request = '1' and data_request_old = '0' then
        -- rising edge
    end if;
    if data_request = '0' and data_request_old = '1' then
        -- falling edge
    end if;
```

The `x_old <= x when rising_edge(clk)` will infer a register, delaying the input one clock cycle.

p.s. I'm assuming `data_request` is already synchronous to `clk`. Else you first need to synchronize it.

p.s.2 I'm writing the `when rising_edge(clk);` as a minimal construct, which most FPGA synthesis tools will accept. If yours does not, you need to write a whole process.

Comment: When do you update data_request_old ? You are on an asynchronous system..

Comment: @kingsjester I don't understand your question. Could you please rephrase it? I am not on any system.

Comment: The component is asynchronous so when do you update `data_request_old` ? I suppose it's the previous value of `data_request` but on an asynchronous system you can't update it on a clock edge. So I suppose you update it when `data_request` value change, which means on a falling edge or rising edge of `data_request` which is just what you are trying to implement...

Comment: @King'sjester First off: I am not trying to implement anything. I am just helping the person that asked the question. Secondly, it is not sure what the asker wants to achieve: synchronous or asynchronous. Then on the contents: the asker reports an error from a Xilinx synthesis tool. Thus he is synthesizing for FPGA. The FPGA logic building blocks consist of look-up table (LUT) - register pairs, aimed at synchronous design. Designing asynchronous communication in FPGA's is very very difficult, as you have to manually set all timing paths for timing closure. I would advice against it, unless you

Comment: @King'sjester ... are a very experienced designer. What you suggest: (using rising and falling edges of a signal) is not synthesize in an FPGA. A clocked process `process (clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then` will infer a register. If you continue with `... elsif falling_edge(clk) then` the tool will often fail. You could continue with `... end if; if falling_edge(clk) then`, which will instantiate a *second* register clocked on `NOT clk`. But if both statements/registers would drive the same signal, you will get a "multiple driver error". Asynchronous design is a separate specialism.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to compilers for software, synthesizing hardware is generally not done on a word-by-word basis. Instead, whole chunks of code are analyzed to find common constructs such as Finite-State Machines. In your case, most synthesis tools will recognize a process such as

```
process (...)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        -- code here
    end if;
end process;
```

That is, with just *one* check for a rising edge. Your code could give problems because you check for both a rising edge and a falling edge using the same if-statement.

To make your code work could be as easy as using two if-statements. However, as [user1155120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392405/why-is-this-not-synthesizable-does-not-hold-its-value-under-notclock-edge#comment77750050_45392405) pointed out, triggering on both edges may not work on all targets (FPGAs). Simulation does not have this limitation.

You could also try adding a separate clock signal which will trigger a certain piece of code on just the rising edge. This code then checks the `data_request` signal.

Alternatively (but this depends on what other code you have) you could check for the level of `data_request` rather than the edges, e.g.

```
if data_request = '1' then
    -- rising edge code
else
    -- falling edge code
end if;
```

Comment: Won't this fix cause problems with things "rising edge code" that is like A=A+1, where the increment will spin out of control?

Comment: If you do indeed have such statements, level-triggered code is not for you. Try the other two suggestions which are still edge-triggered.